# How to set scroll position to top of a listview

Tags: android

I have a listview,I want to refresh it when a button is clicked.My problem is when the scroll postion is at the bottom of listview if I refresh the listview by clearing the adapter, again the scroll position will be at the bottom of the listview.I want the scroll postion to be focused at the top of the listview.

Comment: why would you need code for that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

check this

```
listview.setSelection(0);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection%28int%29

Answer (score 7):

Try using:

```
myListView.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, with position to 0/1.

```
yourListView.setSelection(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```
list.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```